# Modifying default behavior of 'Logoff' Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy, logoff

I have an appliance that runs windows 7 pro, and is very locked down as to what a user is able to do. When it is running in the standard case, the only options the user has are logoff, restart, or shutdown. There is no possibility of having unsaved data or anything of the kind. I want the logoff process to be speedy, ruthlessly kill any laggard processes that might be hanging around, and not prompt the user to end any tasks. I've googled around a good bit, and found the GPO

computer/administrative templates/system/shutdown options/turn off automatic termination of applications that block or...

which enabling stopped the pretty graphics around stopping processes, but didn't make them go away.

I also attempted to mess with the registry, under hku/.default/control panel/desktop, waittokillapptimemout, waittokillservicetimemout, autoendtasks, and hungapptimeout. but really those didn't seem to have a noticeable effect.

As it is, I'm running a logoff script through the GPO that kills all the processes that would show up as needing to be killed, so the waiting to close dialogue is only up for a few seconds, but it's a few seconds too many.

if I logoff with the command line 'shutdown -l' it does what I want. there are no dialogues, no waiting, no nothing. is there a way to set this to the default behavior for ctrl alt del -- logoff? is there some other way to get the logoff process to be silent from the users side?

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Yes, add this to your logoff script: "shutdown -l" so when a user logs off this script is run and they should be logged off more forcefully. Note that using this command isn't flawless, and the only guaranteed way to kill all processes and logout is "shutdown -s -t 001" which will logoff the user in 1 second but also shutdown the computer, rather than logoff. You could consider using that for your shutdown script however.